# JQuery auto complete with JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am trying to fill a Javascript array inside a javascript functions using JSTL. My purpose is to make the JQuery auto complete feature work with my web application which is developed using `Servlets` and `jsp`. The original link to the JQuery auto completionis here - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Below is my code

**index.jsp**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var availableTags=[] ;

                <c:forEach var="list" items="${requestScope['list']}">
                     availableTags.push('${list.drug_name}');
                </c:forEach>

                $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Combo"> 
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
                <input name="selectBox" id="tags">
                <input type="submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

I am calling the index.jsp from a servlet, like below.

```
List<Names> list=names.readNames(file);       

            request.setAttribute("list", list);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/Index.jsp");            
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Here the `List<Names> list=names.readNames(file);` returns a bean of `Names`. `Names` is just a simple class with setters and getters fer one variable `name` which is type String.

However I was not able to achieve this, because the autofilling is not working in this way. Most probably because there is an error in inserting data to the array. what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Open the developer tools (F12) and go to console. Are there any errors there?

Comment: @alkis: Thank you a lot, there was a "uncaught exception: unexpected string" issue. I fixed it. Please provide your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the developer tools (F12) and go to console.
There will be some errors there.

Answer (score 0):

use the var name as **item** instead of **list**

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${requestScope['list']}">
                     availableTags.push('${item.drug_name}');
</c:forEach>
```